# Rendering data from Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, express

I am using express js to render my page with some data. The response that I am sending to client side has multiple objects in it. The code I have written is as below -

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var delivCount  = require('./serv_delivered.js');
var serv_ontime = require('./serv_ontime.js');
var delayedCount = require('./serv_delayed.js');
var crtidelayedCount = require('./serv_crit_delayed.js');
var chartData = [{
        "country": "Czech",
        "litres": 301.9
    }, {
        "country": "Ireland",
        "litres": 201.1
    }, {
        "country": "Germany",
        "litres": 165.8
    }, {
        "country": "Pak",
        "litres": 139.9
    }, {
        "country": "Austria",
        "litres": 128.3
    }, {
        "country": "UK",
        "litres": 99
    }] ;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/src/views');

var bookRouter= express.Router();
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
            delivCount(function(error, res_deliv){
                serv_ontime(function(error, res_ontime){
                    delayedCount(function(error, res_delayed){
                        crtidelayedCount(function(error, res_cdelayed){
                            /* res.render('index', {title: "Hello From Render",
                                    res: {res_deliv,res_ontime,res_delayed,res_cdelayed,chartData}     
                                }); */
                                //console.log(result);
                                res.send({res_deliv,res_ontime,res_delayed,res_cdelayed,chartData});
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
    }); 

app.listen(port,function(err){
    console.log('running server on port'+ port);
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>
        </title>
  </head>
<body>

<p>Count 1 = <%= res.res_deliv.CNT_DELIV %> </p>
<p>Count 1 = <%= res.res_ontime.CNT_ONTIME%> </p>
<p>Count 1 = <%= res.res_delayed.CNT_DELAYED%> </p>
<p>Count 1 = <%= res.res_cdelayed.CNT_CDELAYED%> </p>
<p>Chart data: =<%res.chartData%> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, when I am only using **res.send** the output that I am getting on the localhost is like this -

[image: Response]

Moreover, when I am using **res.render** and passing the same and trying to use thses values on client side as done in **index.ejs** I am getting 'undefined' in all those places and data is not getting displayed. Can anyone help me use this data on the client side?

Comment: Afaik, you do `res.render('index', { chartData: chartData });`, passing a data object to the template engine. The passed object's keys can be used to access the value inside the template.

Comment: Yes. I got it working. I changed the notation to array and accessed the elements like this:  <%= res[0][0]['CNT_DELIV']%> . This worked.